# Hacking HTML cells with CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a html table that has 2 cells in a row. How can I make the second cell appear below the first one instead of next to it? I can only do it in CSS and it's a dirty hack, but ... I still need it.

Comment: and you are certain you cannot insert a new row instead of using a cell?

Comment: As you can see from the answers, there's no really good universal solution. There's no chance of using jQuery to manipulate the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these to the cell style to make it work in IE:

```
float:left;
clear:both;
```

Comment: Hm, it seems that a simple float:left on both cells does the job. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: the float by itself works if you explicitly set the table and cell widths to force each cell to a new line. If you have auto width on the table and cells, you will need the clear:both.

Answer (score 1):

change the display to block
tr td{
    display:block;
}

Answer (score 0):

With out affecting the whole table it's not possible.

You can set the `display` of the table cells to `block`:

```
#your-table-id, #your-table-id tr, #your-table-id td {
  display: block;
}
```

<s>You could try this with only the row you want, but those cell will most likely be renders after the rest of the table.</s>

Edit: Actually it dies work with just a row: http://jsfiddle.net/JzkLZ/

Caveat: This won't work in IE<s>6</s>.

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
table{
    width: 100px;
}
.block{
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: block;
    width: 100px
}
```

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="block">
            First Cell
        </td>
        <td class="block">
            Second Cell
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Try it: http://jsfiddle.net/LKFC5/1/

If possible you should try to edit the HTML instead of hacking it with CSS :)

Answer (score 0):

How your code look like?

I would rather use jQuery not CSS

Comment: I'd rather write correct implementation so that i woulnd't have to hack it. How many times will i have to repeat that i can't.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't do that only with CSS